Mockito - Mocking beans for selenium end-to-end tests
We are currently working on migrating old JMockit tests to Mockito. This includes some selenium integration tests.
public class SomeTest extends SeleniumIntegrationTest {
     @Mocked
     private HttpToolBoxFactory httpToolBoxFactory;

     new Expectations() {{
         httpToolBoxFactory.getDataToolBox();
         this.result = dataToolBoxMock;
     }};
 }

The issue seems to arise from the fact that Mockito only mocks on the local thread and the webdriver is launched on a different thread (am I saying that correctly?). Is there a known workaround for this?
I realise that in general mocking should be avoided for integration tests, but since this is legacy code I would prefer to find a way to make the test pass and not alter production code.
I have tried mocking the object with plain mockito mocks with no succes.
mockito in other threads
I have tried the suggestions regarding the completableFuture:
MockedStatic<CompletableFuture>  mockCompletableFuture = mockStatic(CompletableFuture.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
mockCompletableFuture.when(() -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(any()))
    .thenAnswer(
            new Answer<CompletableFuture<Void>>() {
                @Override
                public CompletableFuture<Void> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                        throws Throwable {
                    Executor currentThread = Runnable::run;
                    Runnable runnable = invocation.getArgument(0);
                    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable, currentThread);
                }
            });

Another suggestions was to mock the executor, but I'm not entirely sure what executor is used for selenium (if any at all)
